# What is the right way to translate the computation time on one device to another?

Tags: python, computer-science, computation-theory

I am working on a Genetic Algorithm written in python for my master thesis. The company involved wants the computation time to be no more than 1 minute. The GA will be implemented on a Windows tablet. The development of the GA is done on a 2013 MacBook Air. For evaluation, I want to run the GA a 100 times on AWS/AZURE/.. for different parameter settings and various situations. Is there a measure like CPU speed/teraflops/... used to translate the computation time of my Macbook or the cloud service to an approximation of the computation time on the windows tablet. Of course, other methods are appreciated as well.

I know a computer is complicated and many aspects influence computation time. I think the most simplified solution could be something like:

```
COMPUTATION_TIME_ON_MACBOOK = 50. #In seconds
SOME_SPEED_MEASURE_OF_MACBOOK = 600
SOME_SPEED_MEASURE_OF_WINDOWS_TABLET = 400

COMPUATION_TIME_ON_WINDOWS_TABLET = COMPUTATION_TIME_ON_MACBOOK * SOME_SPEED_MEASURE_OF_MACBOOK / SOME_SPEED_MEASURE_OF_WINDOWS_TABLET

print(COMPUATION_TIME_ON_WINDOWS_TABLET)
75 #An approximation of the computation time on the windows tablet in seconds
```

Comment: There can't be a simple calculation that is guaranteed to work. Even on the same computer processing speed can change depending on various other factors. I think the point of this restriction is that you put effort into optimization, and cut off the script at the right timing to see results that are comparable with others

Comment: @OferSadan Especially since GAs can pretty much run forever, and be cut off at basically any point in time. The question is still somewhat valuable as OP likely wants an estimation how good the results of the GA will be if he runs it for X amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is to create a performance model with parameters you hypothesize will be sufficient - processor frequency, DRAM frequency, SDD/HDD read & write rates, network up/down bandwidth and latency, etc. - and then run for several hardware configurations. Once you have data you can find coefficients by fitting your model to the results. If you find parameters that fit well, then you can use that. Otherwise, you might need to adjust the model.

For example, if CPU freq is X, DRAM freq is Y, SDD read/write is Z, no network or anything else implicated, your model might be like:

```
T(n) = (A/X +B/Y + CZ)n
```

I'd recommend you pick one representative problem instance per iteration, so fixed n, and then see if and how the parameters change as a function of n. Good luck!